# Wrong pixel values when using padded local buffer OpenCL

Tags: c++, image-processing, boost, parallel-processing, opencl

I'm facing an unexpected result when I use a local buffer to copy data in an OpenCL kernel. The code presented here is quite simple (and useless since I don't need to use a local buffer for such an operation), but this is a first step for convolution-like processes.

Here is my code :

```
std::string implementCopyFromLocalKernel()
{
    return BOOST_COMPUTE_STRINGIZE_SOURCE(
    __kernel void copyFromLocal_knl(__global const float* in,
                                    const ulong sizeX, const ulong sizeY,
                                    const int filterRadiusX, const int filterRadiusY,
                                    __local float* localImage,
                                    const ulong localSizeX, const ulong localSizeY,
                                    __global float* out)
    {
        // Store each work-item’s unique row and column
        const int x = get_global_id(0);
        const int y = get_global_id(1);

        // Group size
        int groupSizeX = get_local_size(0);
        int groupSizeY = get_local_size(1);

        // Determine the size of the work group output region
        int groupIdX = get_group_id(0);
        int groupIdY = get_group_id(1);

        // Determine the local ID of each work item
        int localX = get_local_id(0);
        int localY = get_local_id(1);

        // Padding
        int paddingX = filterRadiusX;
        int paddingY = filterRadiusY;

        // Cache the data to local memory
        // Copy the data for the current coordinates
        localImage[localX + localY*localSizeX] = in[x + y * sizeX];

        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

        out[x + y * sizeX] = localImage[localX + localY*localSizeX];

        return;
    }
    );
}

void copyLocalBuffer(const boost::compute::context& context,  boost::compute::command_queue& queue, const boost::compute::buffer& bufInn boost::compute::buffer& bufOut, const size_t sizeX, const size_t sizeY)
{
    const size_t nbPx = sizeX * sizeY;
    const size_t maxSize = (sizeX > sizeY ? sizeX : sizeY);

    // Prepare to launch the kernel
    std::string kernel_src = implementCopyFromLocalKernel();
    boost::compute::program program;
    try {
        program = boost::compute::program::create_with_source(kernel_src, pGpuDescription->getContext(deviceIdx));
        program.build();
    }
    catch (const boost::compute::opencl_error& e) {
        std::cout << "Error bulding program from source : " << std::endl << e.what() << std::endl
            << program.build_log() << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    boost::compute::kernel kernel;
    try {
        kernel = program.create_kernel("copyFromLocal_knl");
    }
    catch (const boost::compute::opencl_error& e) {
        std::cout << "Error creating kernel : " << std::endl << e.what() << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    try {
        int localSizeX = 16;
        int localSizeY = 16;
        int paddingPixelsX = 2;// 0; // <- Changing to 0 works
        int paddingPixelsY = paddingPixelsX;

        int localWidth = localSizeX + 2 * paddingPixelsX;
        int localHeight = localSizeY + 2 * paddingPixelsY;

        boost::compute::buffer localImage(context, localWidth*localHeight * sizeof(float));

        kernel.set_arg(0, bufIn);
        kernel.set_arg(1, sizeX);
        kernel.set_arg(2, sizeY);
        kernel.set_arg(3, paddingPixelsX);
        kernel.set_arg(4, paddingPixelsY);
        kernel.set_arg(5, localImage);
        kernel.set_arg(6, localWidth);
        kernel.set_arg(7, localHeight);
        kernel.set_arg(8, bufOut);
    }
    catch (const boost::compute::opencl_error& e) {
        std::cout << "Error setting kernel arguments: " << std::endl << e.what() << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    try {

        size_t origin[2] = { 0, 0 };
        size_t region[2] = { 256, 256 };// { sizeX, sizeY };
        size_t localSize[2] = { 16, 16 };
        queue.enqueue_nd_range_kernel(kernel, 2, origin, region, localSize);
    }
    catch (const boost::compute::opencl_error& e) {
        std::cout << "Error executing kernel : " << std::endl << e.what() << std::endl;
        return;
    }
}
```

I reduced the code to simply copy the pixels corresponding to each work item in the associated local coordinate of the local image. Hence, the local image buffer must have unused data for `2*paddingPixelsX` on each line and `2*paddingPixelsY` unused lines.

It works if I don't add padding data (`paddingPixelsX` and `paddingPixelsY` = 0), but it seems that some work items don't read the data from the input buffer or write the data into the ouput buffer (or the local buffer?) in the correct place. Moreover, when I run my program several times, I never get the same result.

This is an example of result I get (right) for the mandrill image as input (left) :
[image: Example of result]

I ensure that the threads are synchronized with `barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);` and each work item read and write a specific data and if my code is buggy, I don't understand why no padding don't gives errors.

Does someone has an idea?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not sure if passing local memory buffer as a kernel parameter is right way to do in many work groups context as it seems there is only one instance of local buffer being passed. Can you try instantiating local buffer inside the kernel? For example: `__local float localImage[16*16];`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I passed the buffer as parameter because I don't know in advance the padding, so I can't statically allocate the buffer. Though, you pointed the problem : all work group uses the same buffer. I need a dedicated buffer for each work group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @doqtor, I understood that the issue came from the buffer passed as kernel parameter. Because of that, all work group used the same buffer.

Since I don't know the padding size I will need for convolution operations, I need this buffer as parameter. I modified the kernel parametrization so that a different buffer is used by each work group :

```
kernel.set_arg(5, localWidth*localHeight*sizeof(float), NULL);
```

I missed the important part when I read the [documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clSetKernelArg.html) of `clSetKernelArg`:

> If the argument is declared with the __local qualifier, the arg_value entry must be NULL.

Answer (score 1):

As already confirmed, the problem was that dynamically allocated local buffer passed to the kernel was only created for one work group.

One of the solutions is to create local buffer statically inside the kernel, for example:
`__local float localImage[16*16];`

If the size of the buffer cannot be hard coded then it could be set via preprocessor:
`__local float localImage[SIZE_X*SIZE_Y];`
which then these parameters are passed during kernel build.
From what I remember using kernel parameters to define size of static local buffer may not work for every GPU (compilation will fail).

I'm not familiar with boost compute but I presume something similar should be possible to achieve by passing parameters to `implementCopyFromLocalKernel()` which then they would be converted into values during stringizing.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I prefer limit the build options as long as the preformances are not compromised. I could also append directly into the kernel source string but the code would become harder to read. It's more natural for me to use the definition of `clSetKernelArg()`.